# copy all TFS data to local TFS server

Tags: tfs

We want to migrate our TFS to a local TFS server.
We didnt find a way to copy all the data, including history of all changes to the new server.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio Team Services? Or do you have two separate on-premise TFS installations, and you're looking to migrate data from one to another?

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools to migrate between TFSs, for example [TFS Integration Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe). But you have to notice migration is a lossy data transfer, please check the Limitations on the toll download page.

Another tool is OpsHub, which is now available in two versions, the free utility and commercial utility, check the download page for more details: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2